# rails - displaying many to many using a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to implement a many to many relation using a model in rails 3 for my demo app.
It all worked fine untill I tried to add a model that will hold a bit more data on the relation.
I have a recipe, ingredient, Ingredient_Recipe models

File:ingredient_recipe.rb

```
class IngredientRecipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :created_at, :ingredient_id, :order, :recipe_id
  belongs_to :recipes
  belongs_to :ingredients
end
```

File:ingredient.rb

```
class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :ingredientRecipe
 has_many :recipes, :through => :ingredientRecipe
 ...
```

File:recipes.rb

```
 class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ingredientRecipe
  has_many :ingredients, :through => :ingredientRecipe
  ...
```

in the ui

```
 <td >
  <% @recipe.ingredients.each do |ingredient| %>
   ingredient.name
  <% end %>
 </td >
```

table

```
 ingredient_id, recipe_id, order, created_at, updated_at
```

Now, this doesnt work so well...

oh well , and a good resource for implementing many to many would be very apprecieated

Comment: Rails is very particular about capitalization structures. You do need the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in the ingredients model, but the association should be lowercase. However, there is more at work here. What does your `ingredients_recipes` table look like?

Comment: fixed the capitalization. edited the question . thanks.

Comment: accepts_nested_attributes_for  :Ingredients or  accepts_nested_attributes_for  :IngredientsRecipe  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a few errors in the model code. It is hard to say exactly what those might do.

Your recipes model should look like this:

```
has_many :ingredient_recipes
has_many :ingredients, :through => :ingredient_recipes
```

Your ingredient model should look like this

```
has_many :ingredient_recipes
has_many :recipes, :through => :ingredient_recipes
```

Associations should be underscored and lower-cased, `has_many` relationships should be pluralized.

You said `Ingredient_Recipe` contains, the content is good but it should be named `ingredient_recipe.rb` and the class name should be `IngredientRecipe` unsure if that was just my misunderstanding.

The first error you are experiencing said undefined method `recipe_ingredient`, which would make sense, the association name is `ingredient_recipes`, the through parameter takes the exact name of the association.

the second issue is hard to say, but I would make the above modifications first and see if that improves the situation.

the third item, I would say no. Follow the railscast's instructions.

The railscast in question is a good resource, I have used that specific one before.

EDIT, just noticed the belongs_to is incorrect as well.

within the `IncredientRecipe` class

```
belongs_to :recipe
belongs_to :ingredient
```

a `belongs_to` association should be singular.

Comment: Thanks a lot . I have re edit the original question since I am very confused with the naming convention. I changed the association name. if you can tell me what exactly is wrong I will appreciate it.

Comment: Fix the associations as i specified, exactly.

Comment: Thanks. really. Alright I fixed it, progressed but not too much.  I am now getting a table doesnt exists. I specificaly created a ingredients_recipes table and the code is loooking for TABLE NAME ingredient_recipes. the class now is defined IngredientRecipe (inside Ingredient_Recipe.rb) and the has many is defined using  has_many :ingredient_recipes. I can change the table name, i prefer to understand the naming convention before. should the table declared as the association? where does IngredientRecipe class declared as :ingredient_recipes asscosciation?

Comment: model names are singular, the corresponding table is plural. But you only pluralize the whole statement. So if your RecipeIngredient class would have a table name of recipe_ingredients. I highly recommend using generators when generating models and then look at the generated code and tables. From the command line, type `rails generate model recipe_ingredient`

Comment: shouldnt it be ingredient_recipe (i before r)?